# extract unique rows with a condition in r

Tags: r

I have this kind of data:

```
x <- matrix(c(2,2,3,3,3,4,4,20,33,2,3,45,6,9,45,454,7,4,6,7,5), nrow = 7, ncol = 3)
```

In the real dataset, I have a huge matrix with a lot of columns.
I want to extract unique rows with respect to the first column(Id) and minimum of the third column. For instance, for this matrix I would expect

```
y <- matrix(c(2,3,4,20,3,9,45,4,5), nrow = 3, ncol = 3)
```

I tried a lot of things but I couldn't figure out. 
Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Zeray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use package plyr. Convert to a data.frame so you can group on the first column, then use which.min to extract the min row by group:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(as.data.frame(x), "V1", function(x) x[which.min(x$V3) ,])
  V1 V2 V3
1  2 20 45
2  3  3  4
3  4  9  5
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Chase. This could solve my problem. The second one is more generic.

Comment: @zeray - I generally use plyr for most of my grouping activities because of the consistent syntax and being able to define the structure of both the input and output data with ease. Everyone needs some variety sometimes though so I gave you two options :) Welcome to SO btw.

Comment: @tommy - arghhh, you're right. I knew I should have stayed with what I knew best...`plyr`.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a version that is more complicated, but somewhat faster that Chase's ddply solution - some 200x faster :-)

```
 uniqueMin <- function(m, idCol = 1L, minCol = ncol(m)) {
    t(vapply(split(1:nrow(m), m[,idCol]), function(i, x, minCol) x[i, , drop=FALSE][which.min(x[i,minCol]),], m[1,], x=m, minCol=minCol))
 }
```

And the following test code:

```
nRows <- 10000
nCols <- 100
ids <- nRows/5
m <- cbind(sample(ids, nRows, T), matrix(runif(nRows*nCols), nRows))
system.time( a<-uniqueMin(m, minCol=3L) ) # 0.07
system.time(ddply(as.data.frame(m), "V1", function(x) x[which.min(x$V3) ,])) # 15.72
```